# RSA verification time

Tags: rsa

For a any processor of these or any other processor

1. armeabi (v7-A, Cortex A8); 2012 TI Sitara XAM3359AZCZ100; 1 x
   1000MHz
2. armeabi (v7-A, Cortex A9); 2012 VIA  WonderMedia 8850; 1 x
   1200MHz
3. amd64; IB+AES (306a9); 2012 Intel Core i5-3210M; 2 x 2500MHz

**How can I calculate the time needed for RSA verification ?**

in another words

How many clock cycles does RSA1024 with exponent of 65537 need to verify a message ?

Sure Times will be different according to processor, that's why I asked for number of clock cycles

How can I use these tables if they may help ?
http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-sign.html

Comment: This looks like homework, and seems to be entirely based around calculating times from clock frequencies rather than security (just do clock * ticks = seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance is more readily benchmarked than computed. Try to arrange to run this command on your systems:

```
openssl speed rsa2048
```

This supposes that you can have a Linux-like operating system on your machines. This will give you the number of private-key and public-key operations achieved by [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) (a well-known and widely used cryptographic library) when using a 2048-bit RSA key. On a 3.1 GHz Xeon (E3-1220 V2), I get 27415 public-key operations per second, i.e. about 113000 clock cycles per RSA signature verification.

Of course, CPU brand and architecture will impact such figures; for instance, one may expect a slowdown by a factor of 3 or 4 on a 32-bit CPU like your ARM (my Xeon runs in 64-bit mode, and it helps quite a lot for big integer computations). Not all CPU can issue the same number of instructions per cycle either. However, one should consider that between 100000 and 1 million cycles for a RSA signature verification should be "typical" on modern CPU (for a 1024-bit RSA key, divide these figures by 4).

OpenSSL's benchmark tool is mono-threaded, and RSA computations easily fit in CPU L1 cache, so this scales very well on multicore systems; e.g. my quad-core Xeon can actually do more than 100000 RSA signature verifications per second (not that such abilities are useful on a daily basis, though).

Comment: What about the benchmarks given here http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-sign.html ?

Comment: These benchmark are specific measurements of some algorithm implementations on a variety of systems. This is a great wealth of data, but it is kind of useless if you do not already have enough knowledge and experience in low-level assembly and cryptography to make sense of these figures -- and if you do, then you don't need me to explain it. Also, these figures concentrate on the systems on which they have been run, where non-PC systems are under-represented.

Comment: @TomLeek While you're correct, I think this is a homework question, considering the fact that he's asking for those three specific CPUs and they all happen to have benchmark scores for 1024-bit key generation in those tables. From what I can tell, the tutor is trying to get them to do clock * ticks to get time.

Comment: This is not a homework question, I just selected these specific processors because I can test on these devices and when I asked a general question about calculating verification time here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105867/rsa-verification-time , I got a result saying as a summary (It depends on processor) .

All I wanted to know , how to use these tables for calculating the verification time.  
Note ronald1024 in the tables refer to RSA1024

Comment: With exponent 65537, 
Shouldn't verification time be larger than signing time ?
I tried
openssl> speed rsa1024 and it gives verification time less than signing time
BTW: I'm new to openssl

Comment: 65537 is a 17-bit integer, which should imply a vastly faster verification algorithm than the signature generation, which uses a much larger private exponent.